# How to terminate the Java process when the JAR has finished execution

Tags: java, linux, process, jar

I have a Java Program that does some web services call. i packed that program in a JAR file and placed it my linux machine. Then i made a .sh file the content of which were

```
#!/bin/sh 
. /etc/profile 
echo "The Script Starts now!!!!!!!!!!" 

export JAVA_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/java/java64/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_29 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH 
cd /u01/CRM_PRD/stores/CRM_COC_Utility/Jars 

java -jar CRM_AccountCOC.jar 

echo "The Script ends now!!!!!!!!!!"
```

This sh file i have scheduled in cronjob to run after every 45 mins which means the above command is executed after every 45 mins.

The problem is when i do the TOP command say after a day or two, I can see multiple execution state of this JAR.Due to this the %CPU usage of my linux server has increased.

The JAR takes 10 mins to finish and the frequency to reexercute the JAR is after 45 mins. So what i need to do in my code or in sh file such that when this JAR has executed, the java process is also killed.

Hope it explained my issue.I am not much pro in linux and Java

Comment: firs you need to find out why your java application is running for 45 min when you program it to run for 10 min. Try to find is there any blocking threads. If java application is terminating then you do not need to do any force kills from Linux

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if all the non-daemon threads are finished, then the java application terminates. However, you can force it to terminate by:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

write [`PID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) of your java process into file:

```
#!/bin/sh 
. /etc/profile 
echo "The Script Starts now!!!!!!!!!!" 

export JAVA_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/java/java64/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_29 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH 
cd /u01/CRM_PRD/stores/CRM_COC_Utility/Jars 

java -jar CRM_AccountCOC.jar & # run jar as background process
echo $! > program.pid

echo "The Script ends now!!!!!!!!!!"
```

and kill it upon [`cron`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron):

```
kill -9 `cat program.pid`
```